# Color map in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy, python-imaging-library

How to use agglomerative clustering to quantize colors in an Image. For this I extract RGB vector for single pixel and this process require for all positions. So again how to extract all position rgb vectors.

```
im=Image.open('d:\eye.jpg')
r,g,b = im.convert('RGB')
r,g,b = rgb1.getpixel((1,1))
print r,g,b
```

this code only extract rgb vector value for only one pixel at a time. How to extract all the values simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.array` and convert the whole `Image` into a `numpy.ndarray` object:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(Image.open('d:\eye.jpg')).swapaxes(0,1)
```

Where `a[i,j]` is a position in this array that will give you the same result as `rgb1.getpixel((i,j))` (with the difference that the latter returns a tuple).